# Migration to Play! 2.5 leads to this error: NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.log()Lakka/event/LoggingAdapter

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-cluster

I'm updating my Play! scala application from 2.4 to 2.5.10 and I'm getting this runtime exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.log()Lakka/event/LoggingAdapter;
```

The build.sbt part about Akka did not change and is as following (with akkaVersion 2.4.14):

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-distributed-data-experimental" % akkaVersion,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-contrib" % akkaVersion,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion)
```

If I disable the conf (i.e. `akka.actor.provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"`) part about clusterActorRefProvider I just get this error:

```
needs to have a 'ClusterActorRefProvider' enabled in the configuration, currently uses [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider]
```

The stack trace does not help me a lot because it does not reference any file 
of my application.
Here is the beginning:

```
1) Error injecting method, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.log()Lakka/event/LoggingAdapter; at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149) at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport$class.bindActor(Akka.scala:139) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> Modules) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.log()Lakka/event/LoggingAdapter; at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.<init>(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:132)
```

I have no idea of where I have to find the cause of the problem...

**Edit**: just changing the version of Play! from 2.5.10 to 2.5.9 makes the exception disappear.

Comment: You are probably pulling Akka as dependency in another version than the one used by Play. Check your dependencies, including transitively.

Comment: Check your Akka version. I had the same issue earlier. Moved from 2.4.4 -> 2.4.14 solved the problem.

Comment: You two are right, thanks. @kecue if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your Akka version. I had the same issue earlier. I Moved from `2.4.4` -> `2.4.14` solved the problem.

for further reading the source can be found [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/92671e6d980b9f23b9d523ad282925b82f54f922/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorRefProvider.scala)